# Encrypt and decrypt Data-at-rest NodeJS + MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

I need to Encrypt and decrypt data-at-rest located in MongoDB. In other words, there must be not plain text aside of ids and some user info.
I use parse server (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server) on top of expressJS
where to start?

Comment: did you solve it yourself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement data encryption at rest for MongoDB Community Edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46682978/how-to-implement-data-encryption-at-rest-for-mongodb-community-edition)