# How to implement data encryption at rest for MongoDB Community Edition?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, security, encryption, mongodb-query

I've gone through [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-encryption/) that explain how to configure encryption which is available in MongoDB Enterprise only.

How to implement data at rest in **MongoDB Community Edition** v3.4?

Answer (score 9):

I was asking the same question to myself just few month ago. This is a list of options I have found so far:

- encrypt storage volumes on the file system level. It is what Atlas offers, and most of cloud providers support: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSEncryption.html, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/security-center-disk-encryption to name a few. Combined with cloud key management it is the simplest way IMHO. The same can be achieved for on-premises storages for most operation systems. Please ask how to do that in [relevant StackExchange community](https://serverfault.com/) providing enough details about underlying OS.
- [Percona MongoDB server](https://www.percona.com/software/mongo-database/percona-server-for-mongodb) has some enterprise features, including audit and encryption. IIRC it uses disk encryption provided by OS, so it's basically the same as the previous one.
- encrypt sensitive data on application level. e.g. https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/rsautl.html. It is a bit more flexible, but you will loose some features like full text search and sorting index on encrypted fields.
  **Update:** An advanced version of this method became available as [Client-Side Field Level Encryption (CSFLE)](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/security/client-side-field-level-encryption-guide/) to Enterprise and Atlas users since v4.2
- buy enterprise license. Does not answer the question directly, yet may be more cost-efficient comparing to the previous options.

Comment: How do I verify that the encryption is already taking place besides checking the log file?

Comment: @jxStackOverflow by trying to read data without decrypting it? Not sure if I get the question tbh

Answer (score 3):

Like [Alex Blex suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46683999/4308032), you have other options than Community Edition.

However, if you still want to go with Community Edition,

You can use [mongoose.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose) for interacting with mongoDB. It has getters and setters that can fulfill your requirement:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/getters-setters.html

In your mongoose schema, you can specify `get` and `set` functions for fields.

```
var mySchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true,
        required: 'Please enter group name',
        unique: true,
        get: decryptFunction,
        set: encryptFunction
    }
});
mySchema.set('toObject', {getters: true});
mySchema.set('toJSON', {getters: true});
```

The `set` will be executed whenever you are assigning any value to the field. It will take the value as a parameter, and then you can write your own encryption logic.

The `get` will be executed whenever you access the field's value. It will get the encrypted value as a parameter and you can write your decryption logic there.

You will have to write the `decryptFunction` and `encryptFunction`.

**However**, you wont be able to query those fields with original values. As the mongodb does not know the text is encrypted.